# I want to remove * from values containing * at the end say 20*, 30* from a column

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a data frame containing the values in a columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['20*', 40, '30*' ],
    'B': ['abc', 'bar', 'xyz'],
})
```

I want to remove the `*` in column `A`, result should be: `['20', 40, '30' ]`

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please help us help you by providing a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without seeing what you have tried we can't really help you in your efforts. To add code, please use [code highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a regex this works:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['20*', 40, '30*' ], 'B': ['abc', 'bar', 'xyz']})
df.replace({'A': {r'(\d+)\*': r'\1'}}, regex=True, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

The brackets `(\d+)` are a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the contained `\d+` checks for strings that are made up of either a single digit or more. `\1` is a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), which accesses the first capturing group defined by the brackets earlier.

The first regex basically reads: Find all strings that are made up of at least one digit with a trailing `*` (escaped in the regex as `\*`, because `*` alone matches either zero or more of the preceding character).

The second one means: Use the previously captured digits and paste them. You could modify the second regex to something like `r'A\1B` to better understand what that means.

Comment: Could you explain me how you used r'(\d+)\*': r'\1'

Comment: Thanks. I elaborated on the regexes. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.rstrip` with `fillna`, notice your columns A is object which contain both string and int , that is why `str.rstrip` will return NaN on int cell , then we just need to using `fillna` fill it

```
df.A=df.A.str.rstrip('*').fillna(df.A)
```

Comment: could you please tell that if df.A=df.A.str.rstrip('*') it will return NAN the we use fillna() to fill the missing values but again filling it by DF.A but how * is removed, as df.A is actually 20* or any other digit...